# How can i merge two array into a single array?

Tags: php, arrays

In my second array I have some value in comma separated and I explode these values and create new array.  Now I'm trying to add these two arrays:

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 0
                    [2] => 1
                    [3] => 0
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 0
                    [2] => 0
                    [3] => 0
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [qid] => 1
            [question] => here is the first question
            [answer1] => ans1
            [answer2] => ans2
            [answer3] => ans3
            [answer4] => ans4
            [correct_answer] => 0,0,1,0
            [creadted_date] => 2015-01-16
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [qid] => 2
            [question] => here is the second ques
            [answer1] => ans1
            [answer2] => ans2
            [answer3] => ans3
            [answer4] => ans4
            [correct_answer] => 1,0,0,0
            [creadted_date] => 2015-01-16
        )

)
```

Like this:

```
 [1] => Array
        (
            [qid] => 1
            [question] => here is the first question
            [answer1] => ans1
            [answer2] => ans2
            [answer3] => ans3
            [answer4] => ans4
            [c1] => 0
            [c2] => 0
            [c3] => 1
            [c4] => 0
            [correct_answer] => 0,0,1,0
            [creadted_date] => 2015-01-16
        )
[2] => Array
        (
            [qid] => 1
            [question] => here is the first question
            [answer1] => ans1
            [answer2] => ans2
            [answer3] => ans3
            [answer4] => ans4
            [c1] => 0
            [c2] => 0
            [c3] => 1
            [c4] => 0
            [correct_answer] => 0,0,1,0
            [creadted_date] => 2015-01-16
        )
```

Comment: So what's the problem exactely? You can easily merge arrays using `array_merge()`.

Comment: have you tried anything? have you looked into a good php book? have you ever heared of array_merge?

Comment: i'm new in php. that's why i'm having problem

Comment: if you are new then get a book/tutorial/lesson and refrain from using SO for this kind of stuff...

Answer (score 0):

[array_merge()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) ought to do the job.
Based on your example, this should do the trick:

```
array_merge(array[1],array[0][0]);
array_merge(array[2],array[0][1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at the php function array_merge

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

also, It might help to see some code as to how you are getting this multidimensional array